# Disable ComboBox of a UserControl from another UserControl without MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, user-controls

I have a `UserControl` `Person_UC` and `Student_UC`. There is a `ComboBox` in `Student_UC` which I want to disable it from `Person_UC`. 
But its not working. I want to accomplish this without MVVM.

```
public partial class Person_UC : UserControl
{
    public Person_UC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Student_UC su = new Student_UC();
        su.myComboBoxName.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work exactly? You get any error message?

Comment: Is there a postback happening of any sort between this enabled change? Does this postback affect said combobox? Maybe sequence of execution here prevents the combobox from being changed. Why not create a global var that handles the combobox?

Comment: this Student_UC usercontol is inside the Person_UC or out side the Person_UC.

Comment: @JobyJames outside, they are two different UCs

Comment: @user2946329 Didn't get any error, it just does not disable the control

Comment: don't create new object of the StudentUC, Use the existing object of the StudentUC

Comment: How can I access existing object of the StudentUC when there is none to access ? 
these are two different UC in two different folder of my solution

Answer (score 0):

Without MVVM it would be quite hard to solve. You have to manipulate the same instance of Student_UC which is currently used.

Actually, you're instantiating a new Student_UC and disabling its ComboBox, but you're not doing anything with your variable "su". Did you assign it somewhere?

Basically, you should have one ViewModel per UserControl, so a ViewModel for Person_UC and a ViewModel for Student_UC.

**Warning**, this solution requires you to use a MVVM Framework like MVVM Light (https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com) for sending messages.

One standard way would be sending a message. Bind your Loaded event of your Person_UC to a method in your code-behind like so:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourAssembly.Person_UC"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Name="Person_UC"
        Loaded="Loaded">

    <Grid Name="RootGrid">        
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And:

```
public partial class Person_UC : UserControl
{
    public Person_UC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Use a Message to notify your Student_UC's ViewModel that you would like to disable its ComboBox
       Messenger.Default.Send<ChangeComboBoxEnabilityMessage>(new ChangeComboBoxEnabilityMessage(false));
    } 
}
```

Then, when you receive the message within the Student_UC's ViewModel, you have to pass this information to the view. Basically, you can bind IsEnable property of the ComboBox to a property in its ViewModel, that you will set to false when the message is received.

```
public class Student_UC_ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Student_UC_ViewModel()
    {
        //Register your message
        Messenger.Default.Register<ChangeComboBoxEnabilityMessage>(message => ComboBoxIsEnabled = message.ComboBoxIsEnabled);
    }

    private bool _comboBoxIsEnabled;
    public bool ComboBoxIsEnabled
    {
        get 
        {
            return _comboBoxIsEnabled;
        }

        set
        {
            _comboBoxIsEnabled = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("ComboBoxIsEnabled");
        }
    } 

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

And your message class:

```
public class ChangeComboBoxEnabilityMessage : MessageBase
{
    public ChangeComboBoxEnabilityMessage(bool comboBoxEnabled)
    {
        ComboBoxIsEnabled = comboBoxEnabled;
    }

    public bool ComboBoxIsEnabled
    {
        get;
        set;
    } 
}
```

I let you bind your IsEnable property of your ComboBox in your Student_UC xaml to the property of its ViewModel (i.e ComboBoxIsEnabled).
Don't forget to make sure your DataContext is set:

```
public partial class Student_UC : UserControl
{
    public Person_UC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Student_UC_ViewModel();
    }

    ...
}
```

Also, take care of your binding issues, see your output console in Visual Studio.